# Apex Charts resizing on page load

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm building a series of Apex Charts to display data on my HTML/CSS/JS web application. I'm experienced with using Apex charts, but I'm encountering an issue that I can't solve.

Once I get the data and build the charts, the user can click away to another page view, and then click back to see the charts again. When the user clicks back, the charts appear as a bigger size initially, and then quickly resize to the height/width that I've specified. I can't figure out why they are resizing like that!

The sequence of events is as follows:

1. Call API for data
2. Create empty charts, and then update them dynamically with data per [Apex docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/)
3. Charts appear as correct size
4. User clicks a button to see a different set of data
5. User clicks back button to see the original charts, and the resizing occurs

I can solve this issue by calling the API every time I show the charts, but of course, that's not gonna work in terms of user experience.

I thought maybe it was an issue with the DOM not having drawn the container before the chart is drawn -- so tried storing the data in session storage, and then every time the user clicks back to see the charts,  I empty out the div, then draw the empty charts and update them again. That did not solve the issue.

Does anyone know why this resizing issue is happening and what I can do about it? I haven't been able to find anything useful in the Apex docs or forums.

Comment: You don't really give an example to go from here. Maybe place default text/images in the elements you are populating to satisfy default space constraints